# Undo all changes since opening buffer in vim

Tags: vim, editor

How can I undo all changes since opening a buffer? I imagine there may be some form of `:earlier` that does this.

**UPDATE**: Many are suggesting solutions for traversing to earlier file writes. This isn't what I asked for. I want to return to the original state the file was in when I originally loaded it into a buffer, no matter how many writes were made since then.

Answer (score 90):

To revert the current buffer to the original state prior to the very
first change recorded in its undo list (see `:help undo-tree`), one
can use the following two consecutive invocations of the `:undo`
command:

```
:u1|u
```

The first command (`:undo 1`) reverts to the state of the buffer just
after the very first registered change, while the second command
(`:undo`) reverts that first change itself.

Starting with version 8.1 (see `:helpg Patch 8.0.1441`), Vim accepts
the change number 0 as a valid argument to the `:undo` command,
finally providing a way to refer to the state prior to any registered
changes. This makes it possible to achieve the same effect in
a single-command invocation:

```
:u0
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this works? I can't find info in the help docs for how this pipe syntax is used with undo-tree.

Comment: +1 for a terser version of what I think is basically the same solution that benpmorgan provides. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that should do the same as the `:u 1` one I had; if there aren't any changes, it will give an error "Undo number 1" not found (which using `:earlier` with a large count will cope with)
The pipe syntax isn't part of the undo-tree; it just puts two vim commands one after the other. (i.e. it's equivalent to `:u1`, then `:u`)

Comment: @David:  The `|` character separates commands written in a single line, it is not like a shell pipe.  The command above first runs the command `:undo 1`, then `:undo`.  The former command jumps to after the first change, the latter one undoes that first change, thus leaving the current buffer in the state before any remembered changes.

Comment: @benpmorgan:  That error message is useful!  If it is necessary to suppress it (for example, when using the command in a script), there is always an option of `:sil!u1`.

Comment: @ib: that error may be useful at times, but it will only be given if there never were any changes. If there was one change and then it was undone (so we're back to the clean state), u1|u will redo the change then undo it, so it doesn't give the error (it also gives two status lines). If you use 10000000g-, then it will say "Already at oldest change" if it is at the completely undone state (which I think is more useful), and if there were changes to be undone it will only give one status line.

Comment: A bit outdated now, but thank you for all the information!

Comment: @DavidRivers: To be clear, the information in the answer is *not* outdated; both the `:u0` and `:u1|u` commands suggested in the answer are working ways to revert all changes registered in a buffer’s undo list in the latest version of Vim.

Comment: @ib: The answer is "outdated" in the sense that there is now a better answer with more updated information that will more likely help more people.

Comment: @DavidRivers: I’m fine with that answer becoming the accepted one. However, to be fair, I’d like to point out that I have updated this answer sometime ago (when I upgraded to Vim 8.1 myself) to include the slightly shorter `:u0` command, as well; the only difference is in the mention of Neovim, which has not been mentioned neither in the question’s text nor tags. In fact, I even point to the exact patch that introduced the change number 0, so that the curious reader could investigate exactly what changed.

Comment: @ib.Your answer lacked the context necessary thereby rendering it "outdated", because I was unable to apply your solution when I needed one. No offense of course, but your answer was incomplete as it was written. Peace and cheers. *e: You are right that the question was not tagged with "neovim" at all, but I had to choose the best answer before Stack Exchange chose one for me. I'm the one who asked the question, so it's my prerogative to choose what I consider was the best answer to the question I tried to ask. Thanks anyway.*

Comment: @ib.You seem to pay a lot more attention to Stack Exchange than I do, so expect delay in reply. I really appreciate your contributions to the discussion, however.

Answer (score 60):

You can use the

```
:edit!
```

command to get into the earliest saved state. See `:help edit!` for more information.

You can also check something like `gundo.vim` ([can be found here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3304)), which displays the whole undo tree graphically, and you can easily jump between points. Then there is the [`histwin plugin`](https://github.com/chrisbra/histwin.vim) which I did not used yet, but offers similar functionality.

Comment: Note, though, that the `:e!` command discards any changes after the last file write, not all of the edits since opening of the buffer.

Comment: @ib: Precisely. This isn't what I want.

Answer (score 13):

In vim 8.1+ as well as in [neovim](https://neovim.io), you can just use `:u0`

Comment: Can you explain more and how it resolves the question

Comment: For now, I didn't find a documentation of that feature. Just noticed that using [count] of 0 in this context reverts all the changes including the oldest one, and issuing one more `:u` results in "Already at oldest change" message

Comment: Works with modern GNU vim Vi IMproved 8.1 compiled Aug 17 2018

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I was way behind!

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation

> :u[ndo] {N}       Jump to after change number {N}.  See |undo-branches|
>               for the meaning of {N}.  {not in Vi}

If you type
`:u 1`
it appears to go to after the first change; pressing `u` or typing `:u` will then go back to the change.

Otherwise, you can use a very large count to `:earlier` or `g-`
e.g. 
`:earlier 100000000` or `100000000g-`

If you put this into a mapping/command, it could do any of these without too much trouble.
e.g.

`:nnoremap <C-F12> :earlier 100000000<CR>`

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around what's going on. I may have to read another tutorial about undo-branching.

Answer (score 3):

To access previously saved file status, I think the following work :

`:earlier 1f`

From the documentation :

```
 :earlier {N}f      Go to older text state {N} file writes before.
                When changes were made since the last write
                ":earlier 1f" will revert the text to the state when
                it was written.  Otherwise it will go to the write
                before that.
                When at the state of the first file write, or when
                the file was not written, ":earlier 1f" will go to
                before the first change.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to return to the original state the file was in when I originally loaded it into a buffer, no matter how many writes were made since then.

Answer (score 1):

A graphic solution:

The Gundo plugin allows visual comparison of changes in the undo history.

Open Gundo's "undo history pane", type G go to the last line, then we can back to the original file.

Answer (score 0):

```
:earlier {N}m Go to older text state about {N} minutes before.
```

That should help... And even you have {N}h which is about {N} hours before.