# Redo all undone changes

Tags: vim, undo-redo

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565357), is there a command to redo all undone changes in vim? Currently all I know is `1000<C-R>` or similar, to just redo a large number of changes, but it feels cumbersome and rather arbitrary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `:exec 'undo' undotree()['seq_last']`

This will redo every change up to the latest change.

If you want to map it to something like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
Place this in your vimrc file:

`nnoremap <C-S-R> :exec 'undo' undotree()['seq_last']<CR>`

**Explanation**

`undo {N}` jumps to the nth change in the undo tree.

`undotree()` is a function that returns a dictionary with the state of the undo tree.

`undotree()['seq_last']` looks up the key `seq_last` in the dictionary.

From `:help undotree` we see that the value associated with `seq_last` is:
`The highest undo sequence number used.`

`:exec` evaluates the string from our expression.
Let's say for example, `undotree()['seq_last']` returns `42`.
The expression in this example would be `undo 42` which brings us to our latest change, the 42nd one.

Comment: I was baffled for a moment because this was not working at all, and not providing any error messages, but then I realised I was accidentally working in `vi`. It works perfectly in `vim`

Answer (score 3):

Vim has *undo branches*, not just a linear undo sequence; this is important to bear in mind. To go to the latest text state, you can use `9999g+` (the `9999` is an arbitrary high number). Alternatively, you can use `:later 1d`.

Comment: I understand undo branches (to some degree), however in this case all I want is a way to reach the latest state on the current 'branch' (the result of `9999u`) without having to choose an arbitrary number